# Bizarre VS code output with respect to Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

On VSCode, whenever I run python --version or python -m venv venv, there is a popup that asks what I want to open the file with as compared to when I run python --version on CMD, there is just an output documenting the version. Why is this?

Comment: This likely happens because the file association for the `.py` extension is not set to use the Python executable.

Comment: title & desc of this question doesnot match

Comment: IDE's offer more features but that means they have more configuration options. For debugging, it is necessary to choose a debug configuration: [_configure-and-run-the-debugger](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_configure-and-run-the-debugger) It is generally a good idea to create a launch configuration in your project: [_launch-configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) Also if you are not opening a folder (aka workspace) please do that! [workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces)

Answer (score 0):

First, the statement `python --version` you are using is a command line statement that must be run in the terminal.

You can run in the terminal in VsCode just like you did in CMD:

[image]

In your description, I think you created a file without a suffix and ran the statement directly, which will not be recognized.

The correct way is to create a `.py` file and use the following codes:

```
import os
os.system('python --version')
```

[image]

Then click **Run Python File** button.

[image]